# Airflow 1.10 - long delay between tasks

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a problem with long waits between tasks in the same DAG. I'm running Airflow 1.10. Can anyone point to which settings that are relevant to tweak? Please see example below.

[image: Airflow tasks]

The longest wait here is more than one and a half hour.

Comment: Just dropping another data point here but I am sometimes seeing up to ~30 min latency between tasks. Several minutes is standard in my cluster, which is managed cloud composer on google cloud. I haven't found any solution, but other people do seem to have this issue. Seems hard to believe that it could perform so poorly. FWIW, one of the main improvements of airflow 2 is that the speed to schedule tasks is greatly reduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing that worked for me is restarting the scheduler. So I now have a cron job to restart the scheduler every 5 minutes.